# Magento2 getSelect Printing Query without any __string

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.2

I have no idea why my getSelect printing query without echo & __toString.

```
 public function loadOrdersCollection($orders): mixed
{
    $pac_orders = array();
    $orderCollection = $this->orderCollection->create()->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', $orders, 'in');
    $paymentMethods = explode(',', $this->getPaymentMethods());
    /* join with payment table */
    $joinQuery = $orderCollection->getSelect()
        ->join(["sales_order_payment"],
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id',
            array('method')
        )
        ->where('sales_order_payment.method IN (?)', $paymentMethods);
    $orders = $orderCollection->load($joinQuery)->getData();
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $pac_orders[] = $order['increment_id'];
    }
    return $pac_orders;
}
```

i am getting following output without any echo & print_r. no idea what's going on

```
  SELECT `main_table`.*, `sop`.`po_number`, `sales_order_payment`.`method` FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `sales_order_payment` AS `sop` ON main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id INNER JOIN `sales_order_payment` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id WHERE (((`increment_id` = '01') OR (`increment_id` = '00') OR (`increment_id` = '00') OR (`increment_id` = '0000990') OR (`increment_id` = '1064535890') OR (`increment_id` = '00') OR (`increment_id` = '10000XXXXX') OR (`increment_id` = '0000146') OR (`increment_id` = '00') OR (`increment_id` = '10000XXXXX'))) AND (sales_order_payment.method IN ('chcybersource', 'cybersourceecheck'))SELECT `main_table`.*, `sop`.`po_number`, `sales_order_payment`.`method` FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `sales_order_payment` AS `sop` ON main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id INNER JOIN `sales_order_payment` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id WHERE (((`increment_id` = '01') OR (`increment_id` = '00') OR (`increment_id` = '00') OR (`increment_id` = '0000990') OR (`increment_id` = '1064535890') OR (`increment_id` = '00') OR (`increment_id` = '10000XXXXX') OR (`increment_id` = '0000146') OR (`increment_id` = '00') OR (`increment_id` = '10000XXXXX'))) AND (sales_order_payment.method IN ('chcybersource', 'cybersourceecheck'))
```

please help

Comment: Aer you sure the `getSelect` is the one displaying the query ? Did you try adding an `echo` message before and after the select so you are sure this is the one ? If the `getSelect` is the one displaying the query, maybe there is some override directly in the core method (this can happen when you forget deleting a temporary vendor override)

Comment: Also you should avoid using `->getData()` on the collection, and use objects directly. You can then use `$order->getIncrementId()` to get the data you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes after some debugging i found the issue.

if we are assigning getSelect() to variable like

```
$joinQuery = $orderCollection->getSelect()
    ->join(["sales_order_payment"],
        'main_table.entity_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id',
        array('method')
    )
    ->where('sales_order_payment.method IN (?)', $paymentMethods);
```

system printing script but if you are not assigning it to variable like

```
$pac_orders = array();
$orderCollection = $this->orderCollection->create()->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', $orders, 'in');
$paymentMethods = explode(',', $this->getPaymentMethods());
/* join with payment table */
$orderCollection->getSelect()
    ->join(["sales_order_payment"],
        'main_table.entity_id = sales_order_payment.parent_id',
        array('method')
    )
    ->where('sales_order_payment.method IN (?)', $paymentMethods);
foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
    $pac_orders[] = $order['increment_id'];
}
```

system is not printing query. issue resolved